# how to set a textview in inflater layout for close mark?

Tags: android, android-listview, layout-inflater

I'm new to android

I'm facing a problem in inflate layout to set close mark

How to set close mark in inflater? how to implement this?

Any one help me.

I try like this..

> ```
>   LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
>   viewList = Nexttopic.this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_nexttopic, null);
>   dialogMarketList = new Dialog(Nexttopic.this);
>   dialogMarketList.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
>   dialogMarketList.setTitle("TOPICS");
>   dialogMarketList.setContentView(viewList);
>   dialogMarketList.show();     
>   lvForDialog = (ListView) viewList.findViewById(R.id.List_view);
>   lvForDialog.setTranscriptMode(ListView.TRANSCRIPT_MODE_ALWAYS_SCROLL);
>   ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = (new ArrayAdapter<String>(Nexttopic.this, R.layout.row_topic, R.id.child_row,tnamelist));
>   lvForDialog.setAdapter(adapter);
> ```

activity-nexttopic.xml

> ```
>   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
> xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
> xmlns:android1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
> android:layout_width="match_parent"
> android:layout_height="match_parent"
> tools:context=".Nexttopic" >
> <ListView
>     android1:id="@+id/List_view"
>     android1:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android1:layout_height="330dp"
>     android1:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
>     android1:layout_centerVertical="true"
>      android:background="@drawable/bg">
> </ListView>
> </RelativeLayout>
> ```

row_topic.xml

> ```
>  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>             android:orientation="horizontal"
>            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>            android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
>            android:weightSum="1">
>  <TextView 
>  android:id="@+id/c_txt"
>  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>  android:layout_height="50dp"
>  android:text="X"
>  android:textSize="25dp"
>  android:gravity="right"/>
> <TextView
> android:id="@+id/child_row"
> android:layout_width="fill_parent"
> android:layout_height="wrap_content"
> android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
> android:layout_below="@+id/c_txt"
> android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
> android:background="@drawable/bg"
> android:gravity="center_vertical"
> android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
> android:paddingLeft="6dip"
> android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
> </RelativeLayout>
> ```

Its coming like for each text view in list above cross mark is displaying....

Comment: What does close mark mean?

Comment: I guess he is saying the 'X' mark used to close the window in windows os

Comment: you want to close dialog in on click of close mark?? or remove item from listview???

Comment: to close that list view and come to home page...

Comment: @dhavalsodhaparmar close the listview dialog

Comment: @OneManArmy: check my ans : http://stackoverflow.com/a/16082761/1168654

Answer (score 0):

You should place your close mark in activity-nexttopic.xml layout instead of row_topic.xml. whatever you place in row_topic.xml will be repeated for every row in Listview.

Comment: if click on close mark its not closing when keep in activity_nexttopic.xml

Comment: You should also write a onClickListener for the Close Textview and call dismiss() method of dialog in there.